# Send form row datas to external PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some help to resolve a problem.

I'm trying to send some datas from a form ROW to a php file.

**Here's the first php code (It's inside an echo and value come from a MySQLi query):**

```
<form id=\"comedivid\" method=\"post\">
    <input class=\"numer-qua\" type=\"number\" id=\"dadivid\" min=\"0\" max=".$_GET['qua']." autofocus autocomplete=\"off\" name=\"dadivid\" maxlength=\"4\" size=\"5\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row["id_tes"]."\" name=\"ord\" id=\"ord\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$_GET['codice']."\" name=\"cod\" id=\"cod\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$_GET['qua']."\" name=\"arr\" id=\"arr\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['descri']."\" name=\"desc\" id=\"desc\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['unimis']."\" name=\"um\" id=\"um\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['quanti']."\" name=\"qua\" id=\"qua\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['prelis']."\" name=\"pre\" id=\"pre\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['sconto']."\" name=\"sco\" id=\"sco\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['codvat']."\" name=\"cva\" id=\"cva\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['pervat']."\" name=\"iva\" id=\"iva\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['codric']."\" name=\"ric\" id=\"ric\">

    <button id=\"dividili\" class=\"btn btn-blue\" type=\"submit\"><i class=\"fa fa-copy\"> Dividi Riga</i></button>
            \n";
```

The form is included in a table. The query may give more as one result.

**Here's my AJAX code:**

```
$("#dividili").click(function(){
$(this).closest("form#comedivid").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dadivid = $("#dadivid").val();
    var ord = $("#ord").val();
    var cod = $("#cod").val();
    var arr = $("#arr").val();
    var desc = $("#desc").val();
    var um = $("#um").val();
    var qua = $("#qua").val();
    var pre = $("#pre").val();
    var sco = $("#sco").val();
    var cva = $("#cva").val();
    var iva = $("#iva").val();
    var ric = $("#ric").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../modules/acquis/dividi.php",
        data: "dadivid=" + dadivid + "&ord=" + ord + "&cod=" + cod + "&arr=" + arr + "&desc=" + desc + "&um=" + um + "&qua=" + qua + "&pre=" + pre + "&sco=" + sco + "&cva=" + cva + "&iva=" + iva + "&ric=" + ric,
        success: function(){alert('success');}
    });
});
```

});

It's not working, no data are sent to URL.

Is it because the form is in more rows?
Or is there a mistake in my code?

I tried with serialize also, with no results.

**Here's the code:**

```
$("#dividili").click(function(e){ 

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../modules/acquis/dividi.php",
      data: $('#comedivid').serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {}
    });
});
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Instead of using a `alert('success');` call, use a `console.log('ok!');` call, that will print **ok!** in the browser's console debnug window (press F12 to activate it). Plus, use the data parameter in the `ajax()` call as an object, like this: `data: {dadivid: dadivid, ord: ord ...}`. Try these suggestions and see what happens.

Comment: I tried with your suggestions, but the result is still the same...The file "dividi.php" needs those data to create a new row on DB, and edit another one. The result (of both ways) is just a new empty row.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `serialize()`:

```
$("#dividili").click(function(){
$(this).closest("form#comedivid").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $('form#comedivid').serialize();
    // or
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    // try to output that just to make sure you are doing it right
    console.log( form_data );
    // or
    alert( form_data );

    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "../../modules/acquis/dividi.php",
        data    : form_data,
        success : function(){alert('success');}
    });
});
```

Since you already tried that, and if the output is ok, then it's a problem with your PHP, so try to output at the beginning of your file what was received:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $_POST );// or $_REQUEST for both $_POST and $_GET
echo '</pre>';
die;

// the rest of your code...
```

If everything is received well in PHP, you need to make sure you are using the right way to fetch your data, like `$dadivid = $_POST["dadivid"];`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 'serialize' method made data like get query form.

so, Data length would be limited in apache configuration.

Try use this custom method.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        "use strict";
        var result = {};
        var extend = function (i, element) {
            var node = result[element.name];
            if ('undefined' !== typeof node && node !== null) {
                if ($.isArray(node)) {
                    node.push(element.value);
                } else {
                    result[element.name] = [node, element.value];
                }
            } else {
                result[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        };
        $.each(this.serializeArray(), extend);
        return result;
    };
});
```

How to use is same default jQuery 'serialize' method.